# Display ACF field from categories on page

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

How can I display some ACFs from a category on a page?

ACF:

Rules: Taxonomy term : is equal to : category

PAGE:

```
$term = get_queried_object();
$get_cat_name = get_field('cat_header', $term);


<span class="services__name"><?php echo $get_cat_name; ?></span>
```

But when I check via `var_dump();` show me is `NULL`

Comment: try to supply term_id as second param instead of full term object `$get_cat_name = get_field('cat_header', $term->term_id);` my be this will work.

Comment: @SurajWasnik no, it's not working

Comment: @SurajWasnik on page template

Comment: Yavar, Can you show me the output of `print_r($term)`

Comment: @SurajWasnik - WP_POST OBJECT ( [ID] => 217 [POST_AUTHOR] => 1 [POST_DATE] => 2019-02-09 08:32:42 [POST_DATE_GMT] => 2019-02-09 08:32:42 [POST_CONTENT] => [POST_TITLE] => SERVICES [POST_EXCERPT] => [POST_STATUS] => PUBLISH [COMMENT_STATUS] => CLOSED [PING_STATUS] => CLOSED [POST_PASSWORD] => [POST_NAME] => SERVICES-2 [TO_PING] => [PINGED] => [POST_MODIFIED] => 2019-02-09 08:42:41 [POST_MODIFIED_GMT] => 2019-02-09 08:42:41

Comment: [POST_CONTENT_FILTERED] => [POST_PARENT] => 0 [GUID] => HTTP://CHARRETTE.COM.UA/?PAGE_ID=217 [MENU_ORDER] => 0 [POST_TYPE] => PAGE [POST_MIME_TYPE] => [COMMENT_COUNT] => 0 [FILTER] => RAW ) 1

Comment: Yavar, you ned to load term instead of this post object in `$term` varibale then your code will be work, try this `$term = get_term_by( 'id', PUT_TERM_ID, PUT_TEXONOMY)`  instead of this `$term = get_queried_object();`, replace `PUT_TERM_ID` by category id and `PUT_TEXONOMY` by taxonomy slug. this will definitely work

Comment: I will try now, thanks )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used simple way.

```
$categories = get_categories();
echo ( $categories[0]->name );
```

firstly select all categories, then select name number of index in array